# Blank constraint in Grails doesn't work

Tags: grails, constraints

I am working on blank constraint in Grails. 
I have a `addWebsites.gsp` as follows:

```
<g:form controller="SiteURL" action="websiteAdded">
    <label for="siteURL">ADD URL:</label>
    <g:textField name="siteURL" value="${siteURL?.siteURL}"
        style="width: 400px;height: 22px;"></g:textField>
    <br />
    <input type="submit" value="Save">
</g:form>
```

I want the blank constraint on the `textField` `siteURL`. The domain class is `SiteURL.groovy`:

```
class SiteURL {
    String siteURL
    static constraints = { 
        siteURL blank:false 
    }
}
```

My `SiteURLController.groovy` class is as follows:

```
class SiteURLController {
    def addWebsites() { }

    def websiteAdded(){

        if(request.method == 'POST') {
            def u = new SiteURL()
            u.properties ['siteURL']
            if(u.siteURL =="") {
                u.errors.rejectValue("siteURL", "cmsprofiler.siteurl.empty")
                return [siteURL:u]
            } else if(u.save()) {
                session.siteURL= u
                redirect(controller: "SiteURL", action: "websiteAdded")
            } else {
                return [siteURL:u]
            }
        }
    }

    def websiteNOTAdded(){ }
}
```

Despite the constraint, it does not show the error when I leave the textfield blank and still takes me to the websiteAdded viewpage. I am not able to figure out what's wrong. I want the error to be displayed in case a user tries to press submit without entering the url. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You have code that looks like this:

```
 def u = new SiteURL()
 u.properties ['siteURL']
 if(u.siteURL =="") {
     u.errors.rejectValue("siteURL", "cmsprofiler.siteurl.empty")
     return [siteURL:u]
 }
```

That `if` condition will never be true.  You are creating a new SiteURL object and never assigning a value to the siteURL property, so it will be null.

Your code is behaving exactly as I would expect it to behave.

It may be that you think `u.properties ['siteURL']` is doing something meaningful, but it isn't.  All that is doing is retrieving the value of the siteURL property.  You are never assigning it a value.

Comment: Thanks Jeff. What would be the correct approach? I applied the same approach for a registration form and it works fine so I thought its right. I have been debugging this for hours but in vain.

Comment: It is not really possible that you applied that same approach for another form and it worked.  This code is never assigning any values to any properties in the newly created instance.  You probably intended to do something like `def u = new SiteURL(params)` or `def u = new SiteURL()` followed by `u.properties = params` or `u.properties['siteURL'] = params` or something similar.  Your code as written is non sensical.

Comment: Thanks Jeff. I am new to Grails. I am not sure what specifically each line is doing. Can you please explain what the line   session.siteURL= u and return [siteURL:u] is doing. Thanks in advance. :)

Comment: `session.siteURL= u` is putting a variable in the HTTP session. The name of the variable is `siteURL` and the value is whatever object `u` points to.

`return [siteURL:u]` is returning a Map with 1 entry in it. The key for that entry is `siteURL` and the value associated with that key is whatever object `u` points to.  When a controller action returns a Map then a view whose name matches the controller action name will be rendered and the Map that is returned is the model that will be made available to the view.  The keys in the Map correspond to variables which may be referred to in the view.

Comment: Thanks a ton Jeff. It clears all my doubts. I got it working now. I appreciate your help.